# Cache is being enabled even if it is set to disable

Tags: cache, ce-1.9.0.1

I set all the cache types to disabled but every morning i found them enabled. I've the default cron activated with the default `cron.sh`. 
How i can set them to be disabled forever (until I put the site on production) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to disable cache by using SQL query:

```
UPDATE `core_cache_option` SET value=0;
```

And clear your cache folder just to be sure:

```
rm -rf <YOUR SITE PATH HERE>/magento/var/cache/*
```